# Apache: High disk read load, no requests

Tags: apache-httpd, io, lsof

On an Ubuntu VM iotop shows me that some "apache2 -k start" processes are producing a total disk **read** load of constantly between 4 M/s and 7 M/s even while no requests are being logged.

lsof shows me about 5000 regular files being used by www-data. How can I determine what is causing so much disk IO while there shouldn't be any at all?

Comment: how many vhosts, how many log files?

Comment: less than 50 vhosts. wouldn't logging produce write load instead of read load?

Comment: Probably opening them when launching...interesting.

Comment: empirically, lsof can show me 10x the open files of the logs that I have configure in my vhosts....

Comment: are you using the [cachefile directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_file_cache.html#cachefile)?

Comment: How big are your logs? In more busy web servers, I change the rotation from weekly to daily.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think so (I didn't install the server) - at least `grep -ri cachefile /etc/apache2/` does not show anything.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro not more than a few MB (maximum 4MB right now)

Comment: around 300 vhosts?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro see my 2nd comment, less than 50. I also maintain other servers with more than 200 vhosts and many times more hits per second with basically no read load

Comment: Same experience here...servers with a couple of hundred vhosts, and the write and much less read load is negligible.

Comment: The major problem is that I don't know what the customer did (and of course the customer says they didn't changed/installed anything)... but they want me to solve this immediately. -_-

Comment: `strace` or such for I/O related system calls might help

Comment: @thrig thank you! strace shows **loads** of stat, lstat and read operations on different files of different vhosts. Any idea how I can find out what is triggering those while there are no requests?

Comment: maybe wireshark or something to see if there are requests flying by that aren't for some reason being logged? or fiddle with the Apache logging?

Comment: useful question when client says they didn't change anything: "*so what was it that you didn't change?*".   or just use `find` to find all recently changed files in /etc and then examine them.    BTW, what kind of files does `lsof` show being opened by apache?  log files?  or just normal files?   is there any weird activity in the apache access or error log? (e.g. requests for non-existent php scripts)?  and has the client installed exploitable cgi/php/etc scripts that might be trawling the filesystem?

Comment: The load was caused by a Wordpress plugin (Autoptimize). @thrig If you post your `strace` suggestion as an answer I'd be glad to accept it since this was the way I found out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indications of high I/O will likely require a tracing tool to dig into the details of what that I/O is; `strace` is a common way to do this:

```
strace -e trace=file -ff -o output -y -p $some_httpd_pid_here
```

- `-e trace=file` traces file related operations (there's other handy specifiers, see the fine manual) though will not show `read` calls that may be necessary to figure out which file descriptors are being read from; for that `-e trace=open,read` or instead just trace everything and then grep the output...
- `-ff` follows forks, good if CGI or such are being spawned, or if you're instead tracing the `httpd` master process as it starts.
- `-o output` interacts with `-ff` and produces `output` or `output.*` files to be poked at later.
- `-y` isn't portable to older versions of `strace` but does save the trouble of finding out what file descriptor number 42 or whatever referrers to.

(`strace` can also be horribly slow; see also on Linux `sysdig` or `SystemTap` for alternative takes on tracing things or otherwise debugging what the kernel is doing...)

Comment: sysdig is much more flexible.